# Augmented Reality : Recognize hand written number?

Tags: unity-game-engine, numbers, augmented-reality, symbols, text-recognition

I am trying to find a solution for this AR app as the topic tells.

I want my app to recognize a hand-written number by the user.

The app will tell the user to write down for example number 24 on a paper and move the camera over the written number to see the 3d object.

This might be used for saving a Birthday, a wedding date .. etc

For accuracy, the app instructions will show the user a preview to tell please write the number 24 similar to this..

Although each hand writing will differ, but at least we do not get curly "2"-s or "4" with an open edge ..etc

So here we need AR to recognize the number, or be able to read the number according to approximation.

And the first question is: Is such a behavior doable or anyone familiar with a similar concept?

After searching similar apps, I found "Ink Hunter" apps for tatoo preview-s, although these apps use symbols not number, but we can think of a number as a symbol as well.

Also as this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9rXJcIE2Fcs shows, each user draws the symbol in a different way and still they get it working.

I am using Unity3d and Vuforia.
Vuforia offers free samples(unity3d packages) on the website, and there is one named "Text Recognition" , and here's the tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3MK6nC5FWE

But unfortunately couldn't make it work.

If someone has developed such a functionality using these sample projects from vuforia or have any ulternative method please I need you help :)

thanks in advance moghes

Comment: My suggestion is not concerning Vuforia or Unity. Have a look at  [Tesseract OCR](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr). It can also be used as an OpenCV module.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the OCR, as I started searching topics with OCR, more tools were introduced. I found an another third party "Wikitude" which again supports unity3d integration. My go to tool is unity 3d since it publishes for almost every platfrom, is integrated with almost all technologies available.

Comment: In InkHunter we have written an openCV lib which recognizes robustly our "square smile". 
You might able to use Vuforia User Defined Targets for tracking (based on surrounded objects) and OCR for text recognition(if you need to show different 3d-models for different texts).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial our team created on text recognition using the Hololens and Vuforia with Unity: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdMeHgD4fMY. In the first portion of the video, we show how to get text recognition working with just Vuforia and Unity - no Hololens required. For your application, just change the text to numbers.

I believe the biggest challenge you will have is the "hand-written" component. From our research, Vuforia prefers computer-generated, predefined font types.